# Verilog logic translation

Tags: performance, optimization, verilog, compiler-optimization, area

How does the following translates into hardware? If I have multiple same equation assigning it to a different register, how does it translate? Say I have

```
reg [31:0] A;
reg [31:0] B;
reg [31:0] C;
reg [31:0] D;

function [31:0] foo;
     reg [31:0] x, y ,z;
     // do something
endfunction

always@(posedge clk)
.
.
.
A <= (B <<< 50) + (C ^ D | A) + A;
B <= C + A + B;
C <= foo((B <<< 50) + (C ^ D | A) + A, C + A + B, C <<< 30)
.
.
.
```

Would I have two combination blocks (4 blocks total) of

```
(B <<< 50) + (C ^ D | A) + A
and
C + A + B
```

or would I only have one of each (2 blocks) wiring out the results into A, B, C, and foo? If the compiler makes two of those logic each, is there a way to ensure only one of each is made, and those two combinational logic wires to multiple registers?

Comment: That depends on the compiler you use. The language does not specify how the description has to be translated into a specific architecture, but it just provides you tools for you to describe a circuit. Most probably, the compiler will reuse the right side of those equations and won't duplicate gates. For CPLD development, I believe XST has an option to not to shrink logic or something like that

Comment: It is inside a `@(posedge clk)` using non-blocking so A, B and C will be flip-flops, this is synchronous not combinatorial.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @mcleod_ideafix, it will often depend on the compiler/synthesis tool. Some are better than others at seeing the repeated logic:

```
(B <<< 50) + (C ^ D | A) + A;
```

and

```
C + A + B;
```

What you should do is write your code to explicitly call these operations out as their own bus and then re-use that named bus inside the expressions. This will clearly show the synthesis tool that your non-blocking statements contain logic that already exists within the design. This will also make it easier to debug in simulation, since you can now easily drop temp1 and temp2 onto your waveform viewer. It is definitely *longer*, since it adds two lines of code. But it makes your code clearer, easier to understand, and it is more likely to provide the smaller area result that you want. Below is an example:

```
reg [31:0] A;
reg [31:0] B;
reg [31:0] C;
reg [31:0] D;

function [31:0] foo;
     reg [31:0] x, y ,z;
     // do something
endfunction

wire [31:0] temp1 = (B <<< 50) + (C ^ D | A) + A;
wire [31:0] temp2 = C + A + B;

always@(posedge clk)
.
.
.
A <= temp1;
B <= temp2;
C <= foo(temp1, temp2, C <<< 30)
.
.
.
```